# GetProductInfo on an XP system

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, kernel32

`GetProductInfo`[(API function)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to crash on XP Professional, while it works perfectly on Windows 7 Ultimate. What is an alternative to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP does not have GetProductInfo function implemented. [This microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives some code to get the version on OS's including XP. Although it is not a one liner!